# Dragging UIImage only when your finger is on the UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, drag-and-drop, touch, draggable

I successfully coded an image which is draggable but, if you randomly click somewhere in the screen it just teleports itself to that point. I don't want that!
How can I make the image only draggable when your finger is on the image?
This is the code I have:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    symbol1.center = location;
}
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: I solved it by using a UIPanGesture :)

Comment: Please post the answer describing how you solved the problem, so that others can learn from it.